# Android OKHttp SSLPeerUnverifiedException/SSLHandshakeException

Tags: android, ssl, https, okhttp

I was connecting google for example: (https://finance.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AAAPL) with android okhttp client, But it throws error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname www.google.com not verified:
        certificate: sha256/7ygD2cyU8sl30bjSfYs6WWBQ1IZVLiPNK04Tfzf5VPk=
        DN: CN=*.facebook.com,O=Facebook\, Inc.,L=Menlo Park,ST=California,C=US
        subjectAltNames: [*.facebook.com, *.xx.fbcdn.net, *.fbsbx.com, *.xz.fbcdn.net, *.facebook.net, *.xy.fbcdn.net, *.messenger.com, fb.com, *.fbcdn.net, *.fb.com, *.m.facebook.com, messenger.com, facebook.com]
```

2 days later, I got

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname www.google.com not verified:
    certificate: sha256/H7hNBz7v4J3Nf2Mj+xzmfoq5xJRS8cXC0gZO+LO06eA=
    DN: CN=syndication.twitter.com,OU=Twitter Security,O=Twitter\, Inc.,L=San Francisco,ST=California,C=US
    subjectAltNames: [syndication.twitter.com, cdn.syndication.twitter.com, syndication-o.twitter.com, syndication.twimg.com, cdn.syndication.twimg.com, syndication-o.twimg.com]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:316)
```

I tried

```
builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

But no luck.

It also throw exception like below:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)`

exception then.

The connection, it works before, but recent days, if failed, maybe google server updated something these days? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems it is related with my proxy.